CLion with Docker toolchain: "The file does not belong to any project target; code insight features may not work properly"
I'm trying to set up a local development environment for my C++-based project using Docker and CLion. I want CLion to recognize the libraries installed inside the Docker container and provide full code insight features.
Here's my project structure:
$ tree .
.
├── 01_hello_SDL
│   ├── 01_hello_SDL.cpp
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── readme.txt
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── scripts
│   ├── docker_build.sh
│   └── docker_run.sh
└── temp
    ├── 01_hello_SDL.cpp
    ├── 01_hello_SDL.out
    ├── Makefile
    └── readme.txt

3 directories, 11 files

My Dockerfile sets up a workspace with the necessary dependencies:
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zsh \
    vim \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gdb \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install cpplint

ARG USERNAME=devuser
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME

USER $USERNAME

RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

WORKDIR /workspace

CMD ["/bin/zsh"]

In CLion, I've set up a Docker toolchain to use this container.

However, when I open my project, CLion gives me the following error:
The file does not belong to any project target; code insight features may not work properly

I've tried the following:

Ensured that the Docker container has all the necessary libraries installed.
Set up the toolchain in CLion to use the Docker container.
Checked that my source files are present inside the container at /workspace.

Questions:

Why is CLion not recognizing my project files as part of any build target?
How can I configure my project so that CLion provides full code insight features when using a Docker toolchain?

Additional Information:

I'm using Makefiles for building my project, but I haven't set up any CMakeLists.txt files.
The source code is mounted into the Docker container using the following docker_run.sh script:

#!/bin/bash

docker run -it --rm --name sdl-dev-container \
    -v $(pwd):/workspace \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    sdl-dev

